# Functional dependency

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

```
        if  x->a  and y-> b 
        then 
        from  x->a  ==   xy-->ay   [ir2]   xy-->a [ir4]
        from  y->b  ==   xy-->xb   [ir2]   xy-->b [ir4] 
        therefore xy-->ab  [ir5]
```

[image]
But elmasri navathe says , x-->a and y-->b  DOES NOT IMPLY xy-->ab 
i am just starting with functional dependency , so could some one point out what i am missing ?

Comment: How does this relate to programming?

Comment: @jim
i just wanted it to look clean , do i have any tags pertaining to programming ?

Comment: The 6th ed. has "X → A and Y → B does imply that XY → AB". (The word *not* has been dropped from the 6th ed.) I don't have errata for any edition, but that's where I'd look first. You could also email the author(s) directly. They shouldn't be hard to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked C J DATE , where in chapter 11 , page 339 it lists a rule called composition  , if a->b , c->d then ac->bd , so that answers part of my query  but  am curious as to why it says otherwise in navathe .

Answer (score 0):

Although my knowledge on functional dependencies is not complete at all, I do not see any mistakes in your way of thoughs.

Could you provide an excerpt of the text?

I found a copy of the book I guess you are referring to online: http://cecfoces.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/elmasri-navathe-fundamentals-of-database-systems-3rd-ed1.pdf

Could you please indicate where they say x-->a and y-->b DOES NOT IMPLY xy-->ab?

Comment: page 353 , second paragraph ,yes you are right about the book , i found a copy in google books [link](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=v_j0CSS3m7MC&pg=PA335&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Hmm , I'm not able to find an example where x-->a and y-->b does not imply xy-->ab.. I'm sorry, but I'm not able to help you out here.